# how to use v.in.ply in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

I want to import a ply file in GRASS using v.in.ply . However, I don't know what I should write in the "input =" field . Should I paste the way to my file on my computer (C:\Users\Marion\Documents\Photogrammetrie\test)? I tried doing so and it send me the error : "cannot open input file". 
If not what should I put?

Comment: The name or the path of the .ply file

Comment: I out the path of the file but I get an error: "Binary PLY format is not yet supported", have you ever had it?

Comment: The PLY file format has 3 formats: ascii, binary_little_endian and binary_big_endian. `v.in.ply` only reads the ascii format

Comment: do you think I can convert my PLY file into an ASCII one?

Comment: Yes , [Convert between ASCII and Binary PLY File Formats](https://codeyarns.com/2011/08/20/convert-between-ascii-and-binary-ply-file-formats/) for example

Comment: I tried it, but I now have a new error: "ERROR: Wrong number of properties" , do you know what it is?